# How to connect to solr using solrnet

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, solr, solrnet

I'm new to solr and solrnet, I downloaded solr-6.1.0  and I ran it, the problem is this line:

```
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Test>>();
```

It always throws a NullReferenceException and I cannot do any indexing or searching.
In `global.asax` I have this line:

```
Startup.Init<TextFile>(new SolrConnection("http://localhost:8983/solr/test"));
```

This is the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/SampleSolrApp as reference to compare with your own code.

Comment: Thanks it is working